# Write RSpec for include method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Need to write RSpec for specific function:

```rb
def display_type(record,house_record)
  #user_value = either user will provide input through enviroment, else it will be ['dctEng']
  user_value =
    if ENV['USER_VALUE'].nil?
      ServiceConfig[:USER_VALUE]
    else
      ENV['USER_VALUE'].split(',')
    end
  user_value.map!(&:downcase)
  myArr = [
    'ani',
    'awe',
    'emi'
  ]
  if user_value.include?(record[:mnemonic].downcase)
    return (myArr.include?(house_record[:name] || house_record[:mnemonic]) ? true : false)
  else
    return [true, false].sample
  end
end
```

I tried this one:

I have added the variable record and house_record but don't know how to properly write testcase for this method

```rb
describe '#display_type' do
let(:record) do
    {
      name: 'test_name',
      mnemonic: 'test_schema_name1'
    }
 end
 
 let(:house_record) do
    {
      name: 'test_name',
      mnemonic: 'test_mnemonic',
      row: true,
      col: true
    }
 end
  let(:user_value) do [
    'test_name1',
    'test_name2'
  ] end
  let(:myArr) do [
    'test1',
    'test2',
    'test3',
    'test4'
  ] end

#updated_code:
it 'should include record[:mnemonic] in myArr array' do
    result = display_type(record,house_record)
    expect([true]).to include(result)
end
it 'should not include record[:mnemonic] in myArr array' do
    result = display_type(record,house_record2)
    expect([true,false]).to include(result)
end
end
```

But don't know how to complete it, getting continuous error:

It is not coming under IF block return statement, I tried to check it using binding.pry, it is giving true for

```
if user_value.include?(record[:mnemonic].downcase)
    return (myArr.include?(house_record[:name] || house_record[:mnemonic]) ? true : false)
```

But while running rspec it is going to else block and do sampling based on true and false

Kindly, give a look, I updated one case, how to improve it, because it is not going in if condition

Comment: Actually, you should call your method in the spec, right? You are just calling #find in an Array instance... It's also recommended to use the "expect" syntax, see more in this guide: betterspecs.org/#expect (very useful resource for RSpec users btw). Be careful also with this code path: "return [true, false].sample". It will return true or false randomly.

Comment: Hey, I did what you asked, but it is not going in If condtion

Comment: What are your trying to test here? You are saying you need to *"Need to write RSpec for specific [method]:"* but you are not supplying appropriate values nor are you specifying a realistic expectation. Additionally if this condition is not satisfied `user_value.include?(record[:mnemonic].downcase)` then the result is not determinate

Comment: Hey, Sorry can you please explain me more, it seems your points are valuable and much helpful, but little bit I am not getting it.

Comment: @engineersmnky
 can you please help me to figure it out, how to properly frame the test cases for it

Comment: You fixed the first issue now `record` and `house_record` are appropriate constructs; however now `user_value` and `myArr` have no use here as both of these variables will always evaluate in the scope of the method body by declaration. I still do not know what you are are testing because I am unsure how you intend to set an expectation on `[true,false].sample`. You can technically test this as `expect(result).to eq(true).or(eq(false))` but I am not sure how that is necessarily useful. See [Compound Expectations](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-12/docs/compound-expectations)

Comment: I have resolved it for sample method using
expect([true,false]).to include(result),

But not able to write testcase for if condition, it is always going with else condition

Comment: You must satisfy this condition `user_value.include?(record[:mnemonic].downcase)` and this condition `myArr.include?(house_record[:name] || house_record[:mnemonic])` to check both paths. The latter can be satisfied by changing `house_record[:name]` to one of these 3 values `[ 'ani','awe','emi']`, I cannot help you with the former as I have no idea what `user_value` is. Good luck!

Comment: Hey, sorry for disturbing you more, here user_value is array that contains an input from user or it is array having test_schema_name1. It can be either